# What is the best/recommended way to share a Model across ViewModels in WPF?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, design-patterns, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a WPF application with several ViewModels. Some of these ViewModels have also Observable collections of other ViewModels. I would like to use a single object (or list of objects) as a model and it needs to be accessed by all ViewModels in my Application. Simplest way Could be to pass a reference to every view model but I think thats not the best way. Alternatively I could declare the model as a static instance. These solutions seem a bit odd and not elegant. I was thinking maybe I could use MVVM Light and register my Model in the SimpleIoc as:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<myModel>();
```

and then each model could access this instance by calling:

```
var model = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<myModel>();
```

Is it a good idea or is there a better way to have access to a model from every ViewModel? 
ps: I do not want to use Dependency Injection. It is overkill for my small application.

Comment: Usually I would design the view models in a way so that each of them only represents a small subset of your complete data model. Then you can pass the required sub-part of the complete data model to the respective view model. But a single view model should not know "all data".

Comment: Using a IoC for this scenario sounds like a perfectly logical solution.

Comment: Your solution by using the IoC is very valid and good

Answer (score 1):

How about you create a separate class library project just for your models. That way you can easily share the models simply by referencing the class library project that has only the models in any project that require the models, e.g. a project containing the ViewModels. The key is, The Models and ViewModels can each live in separate class library projects.

Comment: Organizing the project in viewModels and models is not a problem. The requierement is that the ViewModels can access the same data, same instance.

Comment: You can use static fields or properties,  or create singletons  but remember to make your application thread safe.